# Mod_rewrite not send 301 but rather but 200 instead

Tags: mod-rewrite

I currently have a mod rewrite setup like this "RewriteRule ^/?File.zip$ index.php?r=package/latest [L]"

Unfortunately the client that access the File.zip can't or won't follow redirects.  Is there any way to tell mod_rewrite not to rewrite the url but essentially pass through and just grab contents from my php script?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. by using `RewriteCond` and **Exclamation Mark for NOT Equal**

Example

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^smth-you-want-to-exclude$`